# Metals on Atom not able to run project

Tags: scala, sbt, atom-editor, scala-metals

This might be a really silly question, but I am unable to find anything in the web, so maybe someone can help me.
I am currently learning Scala and because i don't like IntelliJ, i switched to vim and sometimes VSCode with metals and sbt to run my Scala applications, but personally i am a fan of Atom. But I have a really hard time getting metals to run properly in Atom, I think everything compiles now how it should but i can't figure out how to start my code. In VSCode for example there is a "run" link above my main method but I can't find anything like that in Atom.

Comment: I already tried ctrl+shift+b, but this only runs the Main file without importing the other files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run/Debug is not currently supported by Atom with Metals (0.9.2) according to [Editor Support](https://github.com/scalameta/metals/blob/cfe00f41c858d04333e28ed21cd0bec0f723329a/docs/editors/overview.md#editor-support)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this is bad news, because I really like Atom (well i could write a button that executes the generated jar of the sbt project, but i think i'll stay with VSCode)

Comment: I also liked Atom (and I made the atom-ide-scala Metals integration for it), but unfortunately, LSP support in Atom is lacking, Atom IDE is abandoned and although there are some community efforts to revive it, I have little hope for Atom becoming an editor with good LSP support.